# Power Consumption in Arduino in 2 Clock Cycles

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega16

I would like to know how much current is consumed by multiplication operation in Arduino (ATMega328P) microcontroller. As per ATMega328p datasheet, multiplication operation takes 2 cycles. I have to now convert it to current.

Please let me know how to calculate it. Attached is ATMega328p datasheet for frequency versus current graph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication operation didn't consume any energy itself. It doesn't matter if ATmega multiply something or not. If MCU is up and running program (doesn't matter what is he doing - add, subtract, multiply, cycling or just doing nothing (NOP operations)) - it consume some power, and the value of consumption you can extract from your graph (if it is correct).

So, on 5V supply and 16MHz it will consume about 9 mA. This is MINIMAL possible power consumption.

Note, that power consumption of the ATmeaga chip is also depends on the working timers, ADC, SPI and other peripheral components inside the chip. Consumption depends on them if they turned on or not (turned off), if they are clocked and also depends on clock frequency. And consumption will increase with each active peripheral component. Also if you have LEDs connected to pins or power supply, other active components, connected to the ATmega or just on the same board connected to power supply, the power consumption will increase.